# Using altered property in ArcGIS Toolbox Validator Class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, parameters

I am trying to script some behaviour into the ArcGIS Toolbox validator class. Specifically, I am creating a dropdown parameter so the user can choose a predefined option and then a second parameter will update a list of items. The issue I am having is, when I change the option in the first parameter, I can get the options to change in the second parameter, but when I toggle the 'Unselect All' button in the second parameter, the items will not uncheck (they remained checked). I have a feeling it has to do with my script in the Validator.

Here are the details (see image below as well):

1. First parameter is a string type. It is required, Input Direction, Has a default value. Multivalue = No and uses a value list so that I can have a dropdown with 3 options to choose from
2. Second parameter is a string type. It is required. Contains Default values. Multivalue = Yes and uses a value list so that the items populated in this parameter (a list of items) can be toggled on or off.

[image]

So, in the Validator, my script is as follows. Can anyone see something obvious I may be missing here to get the 'Select All' and 'Unselect All' buttons to work?

```py
import arcpy
class ToolValidator(object):
  """Class for validating a tool's parameter values and controlling
  the behavior of the tool's dialog."""

  def __init__(self):
    """Setup arcpy and the list of tool parameters."""
    self.params = arcpy.GetParameterInfo()

  def initializeParameters(self):
    """Refine the properties of a tool's parameters.  This method is
    called when the tool is opened."""

    self.params[1].filter.list = [1,2,3,4]
    self.params[1].values = self.params[1].filter.list    
    return

  def updateParameters(self):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    has been changed."""
    if self.params[0].altered == True:
      if self.params[0].value == 'Option 1':     
        self.params[1].filter.list = [1,2,3,4]
        self.params[1].values = self.params[1].filter.list

      elif self.params[0].value == 'Option 2':  
        self.params[1].filter.list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
        self.params[1].values = self.params[1].filter.list

      elif self.params[0].value == 'Option 3':  
        self.params[1].filter.list = ['dr', 'bht', 'cjjjyy']
        self.params[1].values = self.params[1].filter.list
    
    return

  def updateMessages(self):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    return
```

Comment: @user2856 Thanks for that. That fixed it! Appreciate your time. if you're interested in submitting that as an answer, I will mark it as the correct answer and up vote. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "arcpy way ™" is to check `if parameters[0].altered and not parameters[0].hasBeenValidated:`

According to the [documentation][1]:

> **altered**
>
> `altered` is true if the value of a parameter is changed... Once a
> parameter has been altered, ***it remains altered*** until the user empties
> (blanks out) the value, in which case it returns to being unaltered.

> **hasBeenValidated**
>
> `hasBeenValidated` is false if a parameter's value has
> been modified by the user since the last time `updateParameters` and
> internal validate were called. Once internal validate has been called,
> geoprocessing automatically sets `hasBeenValidated` to true for every
> parameter.
>
> `hasBeenValidated` ***is used to determine whether the user has changed a
> value since the last call to*** `updateParameters`.

So change your `updateParameters` to:

```
  def updateParameters(self):
      """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
      validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
      has been changed."""

      if self.params[0].altered and not self.params[0].hasBeenValidated:
          etc...
```

Comment: Thanks @user2856. Great clear answer.